# Create winnable "random" solitaire shuffles

Tags: objective-c, ruby, algorithm, sorting

I've created a solitaire game for Mac, but people keep complaining that there's not enough "winning" shuffles. People have a win-rate of about 5%-10%, where their usual win-rate is around 50%.

Right now, I'm creating an array with all the cards in the deck and after that I shuffle that array, using the F/Y method.

So my question is... is there any way that I can "check" for a winning solitaire shuffle, so I can bump up the numbers of winning solitaire shuffles I'm dealing to people?

Comment: I bet it depends on the type of solitaire game.

Comment: Create an AI that can play solitaire. If the AI can't beat a particular shuffle, don't deal it to a person.

Comment: Any hints on how to go about creating an AI like that?

Comment: Why not make it a rare treat like it is with real cards? Ignore the whiners.

Comment: Hehe... I know what you mean. I'm afraid they have a point though. If they have a win rate of 50% in all other solitaire games (including the old "respected" windows ones) and only have a win-rate of 5%-10% here, then there must be something wrong. At least someone started a bad practice of making easy games and everybody else must follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a backend part of your app? if so then you can store all success (win) shuffled arrays on the server from all the users and increase the win-rate by sending them successes from other users with some frequency.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I don't have a backend part of my game, but I guess I could send back to some database, which games are winning. Very interesting approach to the problem. I might go with this... I'll definitely have a look at it.

Comment: I did several gambling apps like casino, pokers etc on j2me many years ago. And we used only this solution. All (most) gambling apps are connected to the server that gives the initial information data to play with. then it is easy to reduce/increase win-rate or push jackpot.

Comment: It's an "unorthodox" approach, but I think I'm gonna go with it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I read that for some sort of these games, there is no more efficient way than to do brute force checking of all possible moves.

My suggestion for situations like this is to start from the completed state (end of game), and move backwards randomly to create a random start state.

Comment: Interesting idea, but would be hard to implement with some variations, e.g. where you pull 3 cards at a time from the deck.

Answer (score 0):

I run site with thousands of solitaire games played a day. We tried to built an AI that would allow us to understand what hands were winnable or not. It turns out, like many of the responses, that there are so many permutations to win or lose a solitaire game that an AI to detect a winnable or non-winnable game is extremely difficult to build and requires significant processing power. We weren't able to succeed in building it.

Now, we simply leverage our user data to find which games are winnable, and offer that as option for players who want to play winnable only games. Otherwise, they can choose a random game. I would recommend trying something similar!